# Call SKLearn's cross_val_score and cross_val_predict at the same time?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running a nested-cross validation with `cross_val_score` by passing a `GridSearchCV` object to it. Then I follow up with `cross_val_predict` to get model predictions for graphing. Like this:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(mymodel, myparams)
score = cross_val_score(gridsearch, X_train, y_train)
prediction = cross_val_predict(gs, X_train, y_train)
```

This seems computationally redundant; is there a way to get the cross-validated predictions from `cross_val_score`, or do I need to manually iterate through the folds of a CV object to do this in one step?

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing in the documentation it appears that `cross_val_score` and `cross_val_predict` obtain their values by different processes and it is not recommended for the two to be combined.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation